# Extracting foregrounds from DJVU files

Tags: linux, documents, image-processing, ebook, djvu

I tried extracting the foreground using `ddjvu -mode=foreground` and `ddjvu -mode=black` but the file that was generated was several GB in size. Following one of the answers in [rhis](https://superuser.com/questions/231792/how-to-remove-background-layer-of-djvu-file) link I then tried to use djvuextract:

The output of djvudump on a typical page is something like this:
FORM:DJVU [38219] {page0966.djvu} [P966]
INFO [10]         DjVu 3017x3826, v25, 350 dpi, gamma=2.2
INCL [12]         Indirection chunk --> {dict0049.iff}
Sjbz [16716]      JB2 bilevel data
FG44 [5607]       IW4 data #1, 99 slices, v1.2 (color), 252x319
BG44 [1736]       IW4 data #1, 78 slices, v1.2 (color), 1006x1276
BG44 [2332]       IW4 data #2, 11 slices
BG44 [1636]       IW4 data #3, 4 slices
BG44 [5648]       IW4 data #4, 10 slices
TXTz [4445]       Hidden text (text, etc.)

I then ran the commands

```
djvuextract input.djvu Sjbz=tmp1
djvuextract input.djvu FG44=tmp2
djvuextract input.djvu INCL=tmp3
```

When I tried

```
djvumake INFO=3077,3873,350 Sjbz=tmp1 FG44=tmp2
```

I got the error message:
*** [1-15410] JB2 data requires a shape dictionary.
*** (JB2Image.cpp:653)
*** 'virtual void DJVU::JB2Dict::JB2Codec::Decode::code_inherited_shape_count(DJVU::JB2Dict&)'

When I added INCL=tmp3 to the previous command I got a different message:
*** Expecting a valid FORM:DJVI chunk in the included file
*** (djvumake.cpp:369)
*** 'void analyze_incl_chunk(const DJVU::GURL&)'

What am I doing wrong here? How can I extract the foreground of my DJVUs easily? Any help or suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to extract the `INCL` chunk:

```bash
djvuextract input.djvu Sjbz=tmp1 FG44=tmp2
```

Instead, you should provide the `.iff` dictionary file as `INCL`:

```bash
djvumake INFO=3077,3873,350 INCL=dict0049.iff Sjbz=tmp1 FG44=tmp2
```